# Cannot get input by its value using XPath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have multiple HTML `<input>` elements like this:

```
<input type="text" class="information">
<input type="text" class="information">
<input type="text" class="information">
```

After entering different texts (e.g. “hello” "hi" "hey") in these input elements and save it I am able to print out their value using `element.getAttribute("value")`, which gives “hello” "hi" "hey".

However, when I try to grab this input element using XPath

```
//input[@class='information' and @value='hello']
//input[@class='information' and @value='hi']
//input[@class='information' and @value='hey']
```

it does not work (can not identify element with the expression). Any idea why this happens or how to get the input element using XPath in this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to proceed without value attribute in the xpath i.e., use `//input[@class='information']`

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to mention, I have multiple inputs that looks exactly like that in my html and I am trying to individual ones as required.

Comment: May be would you like to edit the question and add the html?

Comment: i edited the description, hopefully it make better sense now? thanks

Comment: What is the output are you expecting?

Comment: im trying to using .findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='information' and @value='hello']")) to locate individual input element to perform actions, click(), sendKeys() and etc.

Comment: Check following link. hope so it will help you.
[link](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10342/how-to-find-element-using-contains-in-xpath)

Comment: why not get the `List<WebElement>` using `//input[@class='information']` and iterate through comparing the value using `getText()` or `getAttribute("value")`..any reasons to not iterate through the list?

Comment: Did you close and reopen the browser or changed anything from the printing to the lookup? can you see the `value` attribute in the html with the strings you inserted?

Comment: No the value is not shown in html, maybe that's why I can not get it by xpath?  Was doing selenium testing and didn't not manually close or open browser

Comment: @ShubhamJain my html doesn't have an value attribute, the value is rather based on user input.. I'm just confused as to why I can print out the value attribute content but can not use xpath value attribute to locate the element

Comment: @nullpointer yes I was looping through to print out the elements value attributes to see what's going on, but I will need to access the element via xpath or something else because the actions that are going to be performed are more complex and involve other corresponding elements :)

Comment: @DanielleC :  I believe you shall be able access the list using just this `//input[@class='information']`, isn't that what you want?

Comment: There must be more to the HTML than you show here, otherwise it would be just as difficult for the application as it is for you to distinguish one input from the other.  Nothing wraps each input?  You could write a xpath or css selector to find the item using that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way to do it but

try finding it by Xpath as follows:

```
xpath=(//input[@type='text'])[2]
```

the [2] being the boxes number (1/2/3). Once you've found the box you can access its value.

```
IWebElement box2 = FindElement(By.XPath('//input[@type='text'])[2]'));
box2.getAttribute();
```

A better way to do this might be trying to select the " :nth-child(n) " of the div. Perhaps google up on that

Answer (score 0):

As nullpointer wrote, you should first get the list of elements using `//input[@class='information']` and then have a closer look at each element using `getAttribute("value")`.

You won't be able to find the values via XPath bc they have been entered after loading the page. In order to find the `value` attributes with XPath, they would have had to be loaded with the page, like in `<input type="text" value="hello">`, which it isn't in your case.