# Find element using xpath with attribute value

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Hey All I am facing an issue in selenium.
I have a form and I want to click remove button, however the problem is that multiple remove button exists since many users in page. I need to press the exact remove button of the specific user. the problem is that in the F12 the user not exists as text, I find it by attribute value.
How can I locate element using xpath where the attribute is "AAA".

[image]

[image]

I need someting like this _`XPATH = "//*[contains(text(),'AAA')]";`    However I can not user the text(), I need something that can search for attribute value = 'AAA'.   is their a syntax or is it possible to search for specific attribute value = 'AAA'.  please do not use ID or nothing in the page since it is changed each time. i Need to search xpath using attribute value = 'AAA' the results will be the input tag, the ID in the tag is useless to me since I need to search by the attribute value = 'AAA'

Comment: Would this do it?  -> `"//span[contains(@value,'AAA')]"`   - You can use `contains` and `@AnyAttribute` in xpaths

Comment: Sorry this is not worked not found element,    I tried //*[contains(@value,'AAA')]        //*[contains(@attribute, 'AAA')]     //*[contains(@attribute(), 'AAA')]      //*[contains(@value(),'AAA')]           nothing found. i tried to locate in the F12 no results

Comment: the AAA is not displayed in the F12 at all, this is an attribute value field. if I try to do search  in the f12 ctrl + F  of AAA no results displayed. I need it to check all the attributes values.

Comment: I need to locate the input tag that is marked without using the id . just the AAA that is written on screen, and to get the AAA is attribute value,  how can I search using attribute value = AAA

Comment: You've only shared a limited section of the html. If you can share the html of the two rows (or more) as text, it makes support much easier.   With xpaths, the `@` denotes access to any attribute in the html.  '@id' is the Id, '@class' is the class '@formcontrol' is (you've guessed it) fomcontrolname ....so html as a snapshot is a bad idea it makes debugging, copy and paste more difficult and error prone.   Can you share a link to the application or update the html to include the fields you've filled in so far plus the remove button you want to press?

Comment: depending on the html - you can get your field with your data then get the parent, then get the relative/nested input.... or you can get siblings of elements... just difficult to guess without all the information :-)

Comment: listen the problem is not sibling not parent nothing like that. I need to find the element that is displayed in screen. the element is not appeared in the F12. If I want to get the value AAA I can use this operation:   getWebDriver().findElement((locator)).getAttribute("value");           But Now I want the opposite. I want to put AAA and it will locate the place, it will locate the input

Comment: the results of getWebDriver().findElement((locator)).getAttribute("value");  Is the AAA. I want the opposite I want to locate the element that the Attribute value is AAA. I know the AAA and want to use it and find the element

Comment: No worries amigo - i potentially misunderstood at first. I was still thinking along the vein of the start question which says "I have a form and I want to click remove button" and " I need to press the exact remove button of the specific user". What you're asking is a very good question -  but i don't think you can do it - see here, It's been asked before and i don't think it was solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979376/cannot-get-input-by-its-value-using-xpath

Comment: There are ways and means of doing it by code - get all the TRs, use a lambda to pull out the one which has a child inputs with your value (via get attribute) then get the relative remove button - you want some support pulling a coded solution together?

Comment: Can you edit the question and post actual sample html, not an image? Also, there's not `AAA` in your image.